postgres на windows запускается сам, но pg_ctl status выдает "сервер не запущен"
Устанавливался postgres из стандартного пакета для windows. После него создался, как я понимаю, кластер и исходная бд postgres, которые запускаются со стартом операционной системы. При попытке проверить статус сервера через pg_ctl получаю ответ, что тот не запущен. При попытке создать новый по дефолтному порту высвечивается сообщение, что порт занят и сервер уже работает. Остановка сервера через pg_ctl stop не срабатывает. При попытке подключения через psql или dbeaver получаю доступ к бд, расположенной по PGDATA.
Как мне запретить автозапуск в windows сервера postgres? В списке автозагрузок его нет.
Как мне остановить уже запущенный таким образом сервер?

Итак, в автозапуске сервера postgres действительно нет. Его стоит искать через сервисы services.mcs. Там можно отключить и автозапуск при загрузке windows, а также дропнуть действующий процесс сервера.

Postgres и не найдете в автозапуске. он устанавливается как служба. Если Вы установите его под правами администратора, то он нормально запускается.
